# How would you apply the idiom "I'm $verb'ed out" to "eat"?

Tags: word-choice, past-participles, innuendo

I've often heard people apply the suffix *-ed* after a verb to create phrase, *"I'm $verb'ed out."* They do this to mean that they've already done `$verb`, and don't intend to do it in the immediate future because they've already done too much of it, or just the right amount.

So I'm sitting in my hotel room watching the boob tube and I'm wondering how would I apply this context to *"eat"* such that it doesn't get interpreted as dirty innuendo. It's a preventative measure, I know I'm not good at that.

*"I'm eat'ed out"* just sounds wrong. Above the obvious potential misinterpretation, it just doesn't sound right. I can't put my finger in it, why?

Comment: If someone has been eating at you that much, you could soon be *eaten out* for sure. A transitive verb acting (reflexively) on the speaker fits best.

Comment: @Kris: "I'm eaten out" could be subject to, shall we say, misinterpretation.  Especially if the speaker is female.

Comment: @NateEldredge 1. In the English language, *every* statement is subject to misinterpretation. 2. Gender references are better avoided.

Answer (score 4):

You have the idiom wrong. People don't say "I'm all [verb]ed out", they say "I'm all [noun]ed out".

E.g.

- "I'm all TVed out"
- "I'm all footballed out"
- "I'm all musiced out"

So you can go with Elendil's option, or go for the more general option "I'm all fooded out".

Comment: However, *musiced* may not work -- the least it needs is an apostrophe to preserve the hardness of *c* there -- ? *music'ed* :). *Songed out* might work, though.

Comment: Past tenses go with verbs, not nouns. Therefore, the noun is *verbed* in the process before being past-tensed. That makes it <verb>-ed alright.

Comment: @Kris There is no past tense involved.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that the *name* of the food with which you are full is more appropriate, e.g. after eating a lot of pizza:

> "Would you like a french fry?"
>
> "No thanks, I'm all pizza-ed out!"

Comment: But, what if you want to use the generic to imply all foods.

Comment: I would say "I'm full up" personally. I think the problem is that verbs with a past tense form of -ed work well with 'verb-ed out', but others, like 'eat/ate' don't. They just don't trip off the tongue well.